# OpenSSL version mismatch

Tags: openssl, version, mismatch, downgrade

Is there a way to downgrade OpenSSL to a specific version because of a version mismatch message when trying to connect?  I don't want to upgrade the server version of SSL, only downgrade the client version.

Answer (score 1):

**YOU SHOULD NOT DOWNGRADE THE CLIENT**

That's not enough of a caveat.  You're putting your (and your client's) data at risk.  Do yourself a favor and look through https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html before using any older versions of TLS or SSL.

If you still insist, you choose the supported protocol family when you initialize the SSL_CTX.  See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html

**BUT YOU SHOULD JUST UPGRADE THE SERVER.

Invest in the future, not the past.**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working again after I did the `apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`.  I am not sure if there are/will be any other issues with the other clients, but time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of the openssl version in miniconda. To remove it I followed these instructions:

https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#uninstallation

Alternatively, you could probably update it. But I wasn't using it so uninstalled.